# transpose of linear transformation linearity proof

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

in here, to prove that $~T^t~$ is linear the property $~(cf+g) \circ h = cf \circ h + g \circ h~$ is used.

But why is that? How come the composition of functions is linear?

Comment: You should write down what the definitions for $f+g$ and $c\cdot f$ say,  and then check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v\in V$, we see that $((cf+g)\circ T)(v)=(cf+g)(T(v))=cf(T(v))+g(T(v))$.

On the other hand, $(cf\circ T+g\circ T)(v)=(cf\circ T)(v)+(g\circ T)(v)=cf(T(v))+g(T(v))$.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come to realize that the linearity of composition of function just comes from their definition.

(f+g)(x) is defined as f(x) + g(x). Silly me. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just check that. Let $x\in\textsf{V}$, then
$$\begin{align} 
\big( (cf+g)\circ\textsf{T} \big)(x) 
&= (cf+g)(\textsf{T}(x)) \\
&= (cf)(\textsf{T}(x))+g(\textsf{T}(x)) \\
&= cf(\textsf{T}(x))+g(\textsf{T}(x)) \\
&= c(f\circ\textsf{T})(x)+(g\circ\textsf{T})(x) \\
&= \big(c(f\circ\textsf{T})\big)(x)+(g\circ\textsf{T})(x) \\
&= \big(c(f\circ\textsf{T})+g\circ\textsf{T}\big)(x)
\end{align}$$
so, $(cf+g)\circ\textsf{T}=c(f\circ\textsf{T})+g\circ\textsf{T}$ seen as a purely functions.